# Colorize extruded buildings by construction years in ArcGIS JS API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I would like colorize my extruded buildings by construction years like old ones red and new ones blue color. It is possible with renderer but I want it dynamic. I mean when I change years with slider, new values get colored, like in this example :(https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/?sample=visualization-sm-color-mesh)

What should I do?

Here is my layer:

```
function getSymbol(color) {
  return {
    type: "polygon-3d", // autocasts as new PolygonSymbol3D()
    symbolLayers: [
      {
        type: "extrude", // autocasts as new ExtrudeSymbol3DLayer()
        material: {
          color: color
        },
        edges: {
          type: "solid",
          color: "#999",
          size: 0.5
        }
      },
    ]
  };
}

const extrudedBuildings = new FeatureLayer({
  url:
    "https://arcgis.geotech-company.com/server/rest/services/Hosted/Hacettepe_Buildings/FeatureServer",

renderer : {
  type: "unique-value", // autocasts as new UniqueValueRenderer()
   defaultSymbol: getSymbol("#FFFFAA"),
  // field: "Tipi",
  // uniqueValueInfos: [
  //   {
  //     value: "Mühendislik",
  //     symbol: getSymbol("#A7C636"),
  //   },
  //   {
  //     value: "Kütüphane",
  //     symbol: getSymbol("#FC921F"),
  //   },
  //   {
  //     value: "Özel",
  //     symbol: getSymbol("#ED5151"),
  //   },
  //   {
  //     value: "Resmi",
  //     symbol: getSymbol("#149ECE"),
  //   }
  // ],
 // ________________________________________________________yapım yılı renklendirme
   //defaultLabel: "Other",
   field: "yapim_yili",
  visualVariables: [
     {
       type: "color",
       field: "yapim_yili", 
       //normalizationField: "yapim_yili",
       stops: [
         { value: 1990, color: "red" /*"#ED5151" */}, 
         { value: 2023, color:  "green" /*"#149ECE"*/ }
       ]
     },
    {
       type: "size",
       field: "yukseklik",
    }

  ]
},
visible: true,
});
```